# how are the memory cells organized on a RAM and how is it related to C++?

Tags: c++, memory, ram

As far as I can understand, RAM is organized like a net of rows and columns of cells, each cell containing 1 byte. Also, each cell is label with an address memory written in hexadecimal system. Is this so?  Now, when running a c++ program, I suppose it uses the RAM as a mean of storage. In this case, as the char type on c++ is the basic unit of storage, is this size of a char exactly the same as the cell (1 byte)?, does the size of a char depends on the size of a cell (in case the size of a cell is not 1 byte)?, does it depend on the compiler? Thank you so much.

Comment: No it's a lot more complicated than that, but this isn't really a programming question *per se*, so it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Paul R How can you become (better) programmer without understanding hardware?

Comment: @Daniela - There are several levels of abstractions between the program and the memory hardware. The addresses are mapped several times on the way (virtual memory, chip sets, memory boards). Also, really old computers with odd sizes (36-bit or 48-bit) didn't use chips at all (because they weren't invented yet).

Comment: @Paul R. Thank you all for your quick replys. This was my first post and I was not sure if this could be off-topic. I was guessing that maybe my question would be allowed because it is related to the foundations of C and C++. Anyway, I will be more carful next time.

Comment: @Daniela: no problem - it's nothing personal - just a desire by the community to keep questions on SO on-topic, i.e. directly related to programming. You might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for guidance, and please feel free to post more questions as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to visualize RAM as a net of rows and columns. This is how most CS classes teach students as well and for most purposes this would do well at a conceptual level. 
One thing you must know while writing C++ programs is the concept of 2 different memories: stack and heap. Stack is memory that stores variables when they come in scope. When they go out of scope, they are removed. Think of this as a stack implementation (FIFO).

Now, heap memory is slightly more complicated. This does not have anything to do with scope of the variable. You can set a fixed memory location to contain a particular value and it will stay there until you free it up. You can set the heap memory by using the 'new' keyword.
For instance: int* abc = new int(2);
This means that the pointer `abc` points to a heap location with the value '2'. You must explicitly free the memory using the `delete` keyword once you are done with this memory. Failure to do so would cause memory leaks.

In C, the type of a character constant like `a` is actually an `int`, with size of 4. In C++, the type is `char`, with size of 1. The size is NOT dependent on compiler. The size of int, float and the like are dependent on the configuration of your system (16/32/64-bit). Use the statement:

```
int a=5;
cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
```

to determine the size of int in your system.

Comment: Most practical RAM I can think of really is broken into rows and columns (not just conceptually) because it's fabricated on a 2D chip substrate. Not sure you're technically right on the size of an int either not being compiler specific, AFAIK if I wrote a compiler that used 20 bit ints on an x64 that wouldn't violate any standards, although of course in practice compilers tends to use the biggest size that can be supported most efficiently with atomic instructions on the target.

Comment: Yes, RAM is fabricated on a 2D chip. However, at the hardware level, they are all transistors that effective form a latch. This is how RAM is implemented. Are they broken into rows and columns in real life? This depends on the manufacturer of the RAM chip. Most commercial ones like Kingston and the like can be thought of as having several RAM chips cascaded into 1 board. It is this board that is inserted into the mother board. The int that you are talking about needs to be implemented as a struct or class, similar to having high-precision digits. However, size of int is NOT compiler specific.

Comment: It is machine specific. I have used IBM's compiler, Borland's compiler and MSFT's VC++ compiler. The C++ standard does not specify the size of integral types in bytes, but it specifies minimum ranges they must be able to hold. You can infer minimum size in bits from the required range and the value of CHAR_BIT macro, that defines the number of bits in a byte (in all but the most obscure platforms it's 8).

One additional constraint for char is that its size is always 1 byte, or CHAR_BIT bits (hence the name).

Comment: Minimum ranges required by the standard (page 22) are:

signed char: -127 to 127 (note, not -128 to 127; this accommodates 1's-complement platforms)
unsigned char: 0 to 255
"plain" char: -127 to 127 or 0 to 255 (depends on default char signedness)
signed short: -32767 to 32767
unsigned short: 0 to 65535
signed int: -32767 to 32767
unsigned int: 0 to 65535
signed long: -2147483647 to 2147483647
unsigned long: 0 to 4294967295
signed long long: -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807
unsigned long long: 0 to 18446744073709551615

Comment: Above was my point, so my hypothetical PJ C compiler using 20-bit ints would meet the standard. Also @Nathan822 if you check the datasheet for a say a DDR module you'll find column and row address strobe lines. They may be de-multiplexed across multiple chips but indeed at the individual chip level are accessed by row/column.

Comment: By the way, you meant *LIFO* and not *FIFO*, it's not called stack by coincidence.

Comment: @PeterJ   Aside from considering a RAM physically as being accessed by row/column, my question is more in the sense if it is always the case of asigning 1 byte to each address. If this were not the case, then the manipulation of data types would be more complicated if their size is considered as some multiple of a byte. Also, at least abstractly I can't see the advantage of considering a RAM as being a row/column object if the cells are numbered in order from 0 to the last number (this independently of the way the RAM is actually built because, accordingly, this is not always the case).